# Rails: allow singular namespace and resource to share a view folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, convention

I have the following routes defining certain resources:

```
resource :account, :only => [:show]
namespace :account do
  resource :billing
end
```

So, I have an AccountsController which generates the "show" page at `/account`.

I also have a BillingsController which I want to be viewed at `/account/billing`.

This is working fine, but one thing that's bugging me is the convention says the view folder for the AccountsController is plural even though its a singular resource -- not a big deal, but when creating a matching namespace for the nested resource I now have two seperate view folders -- `/app/views/account`(for namespace) and `app/views/accounts`(for account resource).

So, this kind of throws me off.

What would be the best way to make the AccountsController use the singular `account` folder for views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I decided it would be easiest to change `AccountsController` to `AccountController` and change my `routes.rb` file like so:

```
resource :account, :controller => 'account'
```

That was a little cleaner than anything I could figure out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of options, but using `self.prepend_view_path("views/account")` in a method called by a before_filter in the AccountsController should work.  It will force it to look in the specified directory for a view, before checking the default.